# MVC UPLOAD IMAGE SAVE IN SQL using ado.net with update (i edit any text box . the image disappear)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Showroom showroom)
{
    objShowroom.InsertShowroomDetails(showroom);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

1. I had separate data  access layer
2. how to update the upload image in database
3. insert query no problem with that
4. if I edit any textbox image will disappear in postback or roundtrip

   ### 5. I will use not entity framework so I want to connect with model using ado.net

   model folder:

   ```
          public int UpdateShowroomDetails(Showroom objShowroom)
    {
       sqlCommandText = "Update Showroom Set CARIMAGE='" + objShowroom.CARIMAGE + "', CARNAME='" + objShowroom.CARNAME + "', CARBRAND='" + objShowroom.CARBRAND + "', PRICE=" + objShowroom.PRICE + " Where ID="+objShowroom.ID ;
       return objDAL.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlCommandText);
   }
   ```

Comment: Tell us something more about it. Something like your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i save d my image to db using ado.net . Hope this will help you

```
string fileName = string.Empty;
                    string servr_path = string.Empty;
                    string serviceId = string.Empty;
                    string planId = string.Empty;


                    if (IdProofFile.HasFile && IdProofFile.PostedFile.FileName != "")
                    {
                        string fileType = IdProofFile.PostedFile.ContentType;
                        if (fileType == "image/jpg" || fileType == "image/jpeg" || fileType == "image/png" || fileType == "image/gif")
                        {
                            int fileSize = IdProofFile.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                            if (fileSize <= 2097152)
                            {
                                //fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(IdProofFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                                fileName = "ID-" + txt_FirstName.Text + "_" + txt_LstName.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyy_hhMMss") + Path.GetExtension(IdProofFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                                string serverFolder = Server.MapPath("idProof//");
                                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(serverFolder))
                                {
                                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(serverFolder);
                                }
                                servr_path = serverFolder + fileName;

                                foreach (int i in ddlservices.GetSelectedIndices())
                                {
                                    serviceId += "," + ddlservices.Items[i].Value;
                                }

                                 IdProofFile.SaveAs(servr_path);
                                }

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "mask();", true);

                                mpepopup.Show();
                                lblMsg.Text = "Min File Size Must Be Greater Than 5 KB and Less Than 2 MB";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mpepopup.Show();
                            // ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "mask();", true);
                            lblMsg.Visible = true;
                            lblMsg.Text = "Please upload an image of *.jpg/*.jpeg/*.png/*.gif/*.bmp file type only!!!";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mpepopup.Show();
                        lblMsg.Text = "ID Proof File Not Selected.";
                    }
```

Comment: yeah i will do create edit operation with mvc using ado.net with create operation my image automatically store in DB;

Comment: EDit :if i update any of the textbox my image will disappear not save in DB for upload image

Comment: You can use JQ ajax call for doing so that will not reload the page. If u think this is helpful please like it.